# What is wrong with my code? Showing Unhandled Exception: System.IO.FileNotFoundException

Tags: c#, .net, factory-pattern, three-tier

I am learning c# and I am trying to do a basic login `Console Application` using the `Three Tier Architecture` with `Factory Method Design Pattern`. I added all the layers and implemented all the logics associated with the login app.
But when i try to run the code using `dotnet run` command it's asking for the input, after input it is giving error

> Unhandled Exception: System.IO.FileNotFoundException: Could not load
>   file or assembly 'DataAccessLogic, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral,
>   PublicKeyToken=null'. The system cannot find the file specified.
>   at BusinessLogic.User.getUserName()
>      at FactoryMethod.Program.Main(String[] args) in C:\Users\xxx\Desktop\FactoryPatternSample\FactoryMethodSampleApplication\FactoryMethod\Program.cs:line 14

Although the file is present in the BusinessLogic.User.getUserName();

Code provided here

ILogin.cs

```
public interface ILogin
    {
        bool AttemptLogin();
        string getUserName();

    }
```

User.cs

```
using System;
using DataAccessLogic;
namespace BusinessLogic
{
    class User:ILogin
    {
       private string m_username;
       private string m_password;
       public User(string username, string password)
       {
           this.m_username = username;
           this.m_password = password;
       }
       public bool AttemptLogin()
       {
           if(m_username.Equals("abc") && m_password.Equals("abc123"))
           {
               return true;
           }
           return false;
       }
       public string getUserName()
       {
           IGetDetails objectType = GetDetails.getDetails(m_username);
           Console.WriteLine(objectType.getStudentName());
           return objectType.getStudentName();
       }
    }
}
```

IGetDetails.cs

```
using System;

namespace DataAccessLogic
{
    public interface IGetDetails
    {
        string getStudentName();
        string getStudentId();
    }
}
```

GetDetails.cs

```
namespace DataAccessLogic
{
    public class GetDetails
    {
        public static IGetDetails getDetails(string username)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(username);
            IGetDetails objectType = null;
            objectType = new GetValue(username);
            return objectType;
        }
    }
}
```

GetValue.cs

```
namespace DataAccessLogic
{
    public class GetValue:IGetDetails
    {
        private string m_username = string.Empty;
        public GetValue(string username)
        {
            this.m_username = username;
        }
        public string getStudentName()
        {
            return m_username;
        }
        public string getStudentId()
        {
            return "2205";
        }
    }
```

In the Program.cs

```
ILogin loginType = Login.attemptLogin(email, password);
        if(loginType.AttemptLogin())
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Name: "+ loginType.getUserName());
        }
```

in loginType.getUserName() is giving error, if I change the `getUserName()` method to just return a string like "hello" it is giving output, but when i try to return the string from object `IGetDetails` giving error.

Full SOurce Code [Github](https://github.com/ChintuYadav/Console-Login-Application-C-)

Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: The error is very specific, it cant find DataAccessLogic, is it referenced as part of your solution, does it end up in the final out put bin directory, is it the right bitness

Comment: Please provide more detail
Login class Source code ?

Comment: @Saruman yes it is referenced

Comment: Try looking with _fuslogvw_, and, if this is running locally, with SysInternals Process Monitor.

Comment: Your source code isn't the problem here... It can't find one of your project dlls. Is the file DataAccessLogic.dll in the same folder as the application you're running?

Comment: @pinkfloydx33 yes it is in the same folder

Comment: Are you using Visual Studio? If so, which version?

Comment: @LasseVågsætherKarlsen Visual Studio Community 2017

Comment: If A references B and B references C, depending on type of project, when compiling A you may or may not get a copy of C into the output folder of A. If you don't, the only way to fix it is to add a reference from A to C as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I can see from your `FactoryMethod.csproj` file, you are not referencing `DataAccessLogic` in `FactoryMethod` project. That's why `DataAccessLogic.dll` is **not** copied to `bin/Debug/netcoreapp2.0/` folder and exception message is literally telling you so.

You may copy this file by-hands and check if your application runs now, but this will be better to fix your references.

***Explanation:***

You referencing `BusinessLogic` as **external file dependency** (`..\BusinessLogic\obj\Debug\netstandard2.0\BusinessLogic.dll`), not **project-to-project**. This way .Net CLR doesn't know anything about `BusinessLogic` dependencies and just *copy-if-newer* this file to `FactoryMethod` project's output dir.

Then, at run-time, CLR will see, that at 14 line of `Program.cs` file it need a `GetDetails` class, which is in `DataAccessLogic, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null` assembly. It tryes to load this assembly from a working dir, but didn't find it, so it throws `System.IO.FileNotFoundException`.

***Solution:***

Always copy this file by hand **OR** fix your references so, that `FactoryMethod` project will reference `BusinessLogic` **project** (not file). This can be done at `Projects` tab in `Reference Manager` window.

Now Visual studio will build outdated `BusinessLogic` project and `copy-if-newer` all its dependencies.

Also, fix reference in `BusinessLogic` project in the same way. 
There is a nice [docs about references](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/ide/managing-references-in-a-project?view=vs-2017). Take a look.

Comment: Why is it necessary to add `DataAccessLogic` to `FactoryMethod`, I have included it in the `BusinessLogic` csproj ?
Can you please explain